# Importing Google play services library to mobile ads example

Tags: android, ads

I am trying to run the `GoogleAdsSampleActivity` class . I have made reference to the Google Play services library but I am getting following error . Please help me to figure out what's wrong. I googled a lot but did not manage to found any solution. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks!

I got the following error :-

```
   04-26 01:01:17.174: E/dalvikvm(1482): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment
```

Comment: same here. I customize the ROM and install the google play service. But I am not explicitly using any showErrorDialogFragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the latest Google Play Service on your phone, no matter whether you are explicitly using FragmentActivity or support library, you need to put the android-support-v4.jar into the libs folder.

Comment: Cheers, that did it for me. :)